# How to perform an initial fetch in a controller if not using a route

Tags: angularjs

In the TodoMVC angularjs app, an initial fetch from storage is performed in the resolve method of the router configuration. How would this be done if only using a controller and not a router in an angular application?

```
var routeConfig = {
  controller: 'TodoCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'todomvc-index.html',
  resolve: {
    store: function (todoStorage) {
      // Get the correct module (API or localStorage).
      return todoStorage.then(function (module) {
        module.get(); // Fetch the todo records in the background.
        return module;
      });
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: You would call the service from the controller?

Comment: The point of the question is that the route config serves as a type of initializer. is there a way to do something like that in the controller? an init function?

Comment: anyways, if you can please show me how to call it and call the get method (to perform an initial fetch)